# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable using cx_freeze

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze

I've frozen my app with `cx_Freeze` and when running the .exe I get this error (only error):

```
C:\Python34\build\exe.win32-3.4>run.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 27
, in <module>
    exec(code, m.__dict__)
  File "run.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\Socket.py", line 5, in openSocket
    s = socket.socket()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

If I run my app in Python then it works perfectly fine.I have done `import socket` in both the main python file (run.py) and the one mentioned in the error above (Socket.py)

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try renaming your "Socket.py" file to something else ("socket_maker.py"). Then delete all *.pyc files from the current directory (especially anything called socket.pyc).

I'm thinking that the module name you are trying to import is conflicting with the object and function names.